# Converting Base1 pointer to Base2 pointer ( boost shared_ptr)

Tags: c++, boost

I have a two base classes Base1 and Base2. Both has 1 pure virtual functions. 
Another class called as Derived implements above two class by providing implmentation

```
class Base1
{
 public:
   virtual void Base1Method()=0;
};

class Base2
{
 public:
   virtual void Base2Method()=0;
};

class Derived: public Base1, public Base2
{
  public:
   Derived(){}

   void Base1Method()
   {
     //IMPL
   }

   void Base2Method()
   {
     //IMPL
   }
};
```

Now,

I have `boost::shared_ptr<Base1> spBase1 = new Derived();`

How can I convert `spBase1` to `boost::shared_ptr<Base2>` safely ?

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `dynamic_cast`. To `dynamic_cast` `shared_ptr`s, use [`std::dynamic_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast).

```
std::shared_ptr<Base2> spBase2 = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Base2>(spBase1);
```

I'm relatively sure this is the same in boost (replace `std::` with `boost::`), you can look for yourself. Use `std` instead of boost if available.

Answer (score 4):

Use dynamic_pointer_cast for shared pointer

```
std::shared_ptr<Base2> spfoo = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Base2>(spBase1);
```

Use dynamic_cast for pointer

```
base1*  ptr = dynamic_cast<Base1*>(spBase1.get());
```